# .htaccess 301 redirect part of URL - how to do it the right way?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a CMS based e-commerce website.

The website is located att www.domain.com
I have a copy of the website at www.domain.com/fi (fi is for the finnish market)

I need write a redirect so that all pages under /fi gets redirected to the original, example:

`www.domain.com/fi/category/product` needs to be redirected to 
    `www.domain.com/category/product`

I tried:

```
RedirectMatch permanent fi(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1
```

But this removed all fi from the url's (even if "fi" was in another part/section of the URL. Like if a product has the URL /product/fiber it changed that to: /product/ber).

How do I redirect all /fi URLs the right way??

Answer (score 1):

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^fi/(.*)$ /$1
```

You can use this tool to help: http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php